# RecyclerView adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() not working from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-recyclerview

I have static `ArrayList` & `CustomAdapter` to access it from `Broadcastreceiver`

```
public static ArrayList<AppDetail> apps;
public static CustomAdapter adapter;
```

when data is changed my `Broadcastreceiver` is called an my list is updated with new items but RecyclerView shows old data new items are not seen

```
public class AppListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Akshay", "there is a broadcast");
        apps=null;
        loadApps(context);
    }
```

And this is my `loadApps()` function

```
private void loadApps(Context context){
if (apps == null)
    {
        //Loads new data in arraylist and i have new data now i want to update my recyclerview
        Log.d("Akshay","totalApps1= "+apps.size());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//is called but not working
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add your loadapps() function in **onResume()** method of activity also.

Comment: but that will get called even if my data is not changed (in some cases) and load my list again

Comment: Can you post where you set adapter in activity ?

Comment: Can you please add your full code where you call broadcast receiver, set adapter and add value to list?

Comment: @JanviVyas I have receiver defined in manifest according to that broadcast is called there is no problem in my broadcast its getting triggered whenever i need it to be, and rest code is as usual we do while setting data to recyclerview item from adapter

Comment: okay. so, have you checked your adapter is not null when you notified? It may be possible.

Comment: as i already said adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is called but not working and my adapter is also not null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168980/discussion-between-janvi-vyas-and-akshay-katariya).

Answer (score 0):

hi @Akshay Katariya can you try below code

```
private void loadApps(Context context){
    if (apps == null)
        {
            if(adapter != null)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            else
            yourRecyclerviewObject.setadapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

please check it.